# Which functions solve autonomous ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Fix an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

What can be said about the set $a_n(U)$ of functions $f \in C^n(U, \mathbb{R})$ for which there exists a (sufficiently nice) nonzero function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$g(f(x), f'(x), f''(x), \ldots, f^{(n)}(x)) = 0$$

for all $x \in U$? Or about the set
$$a(U) := \bigcup_n a_n$$
of functions that satisfy *some* autonomous equation of *some* order?

For instance, are they known to contain or be contained in any well-known classes of functions?

(Obviously this depends on what functions $g$ you deem "sufficiently nice."  Feel free to make it anything reasonable that gives an interesting result.)

Comment: I don't pretend to answer your question fully, but I want to share one observation. If we take $U$ to be $(a, b)$ then we can easily claim that $a(U)$ contains any finite sum of any cosines and sines  -- they satisfy simple constant coefficient linear ODEs (which requires $g$ to be linear wrt each variable). IMO, from here follows that $a(U)$ is dense in the set of functions that could be approximated by Fourier series, but the choice of metric is up to you.

Comment: This boils down to the structure of the set of values $\{(f(x),\dots, f^{(n)}(x))\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. What can be said? Not much. Probably not much.